# Matching JSON request body based on JSON Path with logical operators in WireMock

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, wiremock

In WireMock I am trying to match the request based on the JSON body with path matchers as shown below. But it seems that the logical operators are not supported inside `matchesJsonPath` expression.

Is this understanding correct? What could be a possible alternative solution?

```
...
"request": {
        "url": "/mock/score",
        "method": "PUT",
        "bodyPatterns": [
          {
            "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.code == '123')]"
          },
          {
            "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.amnt < '200000')]"
          }
        ]
      }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect. You can use operators inside of the JSONPath filters. You might be running into issues because the value being checked on `amnt` is a string. The following should work.

```
...
{
  "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.amnt < 20000)]"
}
...
```

This of course, requires that the value being passed in the body is a number type and not a string itself.

```
{ 
  "amnt": 20000 // correct format
  "amnt": "20000" // incorrect format
}
```

If your `amnt` value is a string, you may have to [write a custom matcher](http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/#custom-request-matchers) that can parse the body and convert the string value into a number (or the java data type equivalent)